# How do I know what VM settings (esp. heap sizes) to use in eclipse.ini

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, jvm, jvm-arguments

I'm not a Java VM expert, and certainly not an expert in how Eclipse uses its VM. I've just installed Eclipse on a(nother) machine of mine, and I want to make some eclipse.ini changes. I know what XXMaxPermSize, Xms and Xmx mean, basically, but how do I adjust them to the combination of my Eclipse version, my word size, my Windows version, my CPU, my memory and my usage profile (which language, what kind of codebase size etc.)?

Note I'm not asking for the specific settings you would recommend for my own machine - but how to go about doing that. Also, the supposed-duplicate got answers about one or two specific Eclipse versions, focusing on shortcomings of JVMs at that time; so in the context of my question this might translate into "one consideration/limiting factor would be deficiencies in the current version of the JVM you're using" and then "here's what I know about those" or "see XYZ for a list of them".

Comment: Just leave the settings as they are - eclipse offers sensible defaults. Only when you are getting either very slow performance or errors that you've run out of heap space, increase -Xmx.

Comment: As kenney said, usually there is no need to modify the eclipse.ini file. Yet I find it usefull to add `-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50`
Where *UseStringDeduplication* can  greatly reduce your heap usage.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev: I did not ask about the "best settings", nor for any specific settings. Although, that question seems to have specific answers for a bunch of old(ish) Eclipse versions, regarding shortcomings of the JVMs of that time etc.